# Magento 1.3 - Image upload issues with Flash

Tags: flash, magento

The image upload functional within magento 1.3.0 fails for the majority of cases. We're running our magento instance on a windows server. I've tried to switch the version of the plash plugin used by the browser, with no luck. What other work arounds have people tried to get this working consistently?.
Regards,
P

Comment: What exactly happens when it fails? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

This little line at the bottom of the [Magento 1.3.0 Installation Guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-installation-guide) go me!.

> Known Issues
>
> Magento was developed on Linux and as such, it is most tested on this platform. Here are some known issues that may result from the use of other operating systems.
>
> 1. Under Windows, image uploads do not work at this time. As a result, an administrator will not be able to upload product images.

The default admin user can't upload images. I created a new role permission, but had the same issue. My solution is to backup my DB and re-import it within a magento instance running on Linux. Perhaps they should say magento only runs on Linux!.

Answer (score 1):

This was a known issue with flash player 10.

There is a plugin for firefox that allows you to switch to a different version of flash player (9).

http://www.sephiroth.it/weblog/archives/2006/10/flash_switcher_for_firefox.php

Give that a go.

Comment: Do you have a link to the issue?  I've seen a similar issue, but can't seem to find documentation on the flash bug.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the file and folder permissions? I had a customer's website that I moved to a new server, but the folder permissions did not stay intact. The image would upload to 100%, but nothing would happen. Later I had to reset all folder permissions.